# Kafka Connect: Wasn't unable to resume work after last rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have Kafka Connect (version `2.1.1-cp1`) working with Kafka (`2.0.1-cp4`) and running around 70 connectors with quite heavy workload. Sometimes (every 2-3 weeks), out of sudden some of the nodes start to get following logs and simply stop working:

```
INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=dwh-prod] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=dwh-prod] Successfully joined group with generation 2288 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
INFO Joined group and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-8532b028-281c-4aca-8440-c4c999812158', leaderUrl='http://10.36.3.136:8083/', offset=2811, connectorIds=[<redacted>]} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
WARN Catching up to assignment's config offset. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
INFO Current config state offset -1 is behind group assignment 2811, reading to end of config log (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
INFO Finished reading to end of log and updated config snapshot, new config log offset: -1 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
INFO Current config state offset -1 does not match group assignment 2811. Forcing rebalance. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
INFO Rebalance started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
INFO Wasn't unable to resume work after last rebalance, can skip stopping connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
```

I can see that there might be a problem with getting configState (offset) from configBackingStore, not sure why https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.1.1/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/distributed/DistributedHerder.java#L823

Also looks like it starts since new node is being spawned (it's being hosted in Kubernetes with vertical pod autoscaler) and keeps happening for hours, indefinitely.

The solution works on K8S with `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect`

```
 - name: CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL
   value: INFO
 - name: CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
   value:***:9092
 - name: CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
   value: ***:2181
 - name: CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL
   value: http://***:8081
 - name: CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL
   value: http://***:8081
 - name: CONNECT_GROUP_ID
   value: dwh-prod
 - name: CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC
   value: dwh-prod-status
 - name: CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC
   value: dwh-prod-configs
 - name: CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC
   value: dwh-prod-offsets
 - name: CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS
   value: "10000"
 - name: CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR
   value: "1"
 - name: CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR
   value: "1"
 - name: CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR
   value: "1"
 - name: CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
   valueFrom:
     fieldRef:
       fieldPath: status.podIP
 - name: CONNECT_REST_PORT
   value: "8083"
 - name: CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH
   value: /usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/usr/share/landoop-plugins
 - name: CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER
   value: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
 - name: CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER
   value: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
 - name: CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER
   value: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
 - name: CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER
  value: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
- name: CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS
  value: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
- name: CLASSPATH
  value: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-5.0.0.jar
```

Any ideas or hints, please?

Comment: Can you please share the `worker.properties` that you start your workers with? Do you create the offsets topic manually or rely on Connect to create it? You may be creating the internal Connect topics with the wrong compaction policy.

Comment: I run it on K8S with `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect` image. I have pasted config above, hope that answers your question.

Comment: How many kafka brokers do you have?

Comment: There's 3 brokers

Answer (score 0):

[apache-kafka-connect](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-connect) in distributed mode [uses](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2e91a310d7bf9e7d4d46b0bc0ca0c11cb4531e10/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/cli/ConnectDistributed.java#L118) `KafkaConfigBackingStore` as implementation of `ConfigBackingStore`. [`KafkaConfigBackingStore`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.1.1/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/storage/KafkaConfigBackingStore.java) provides persistent storage of Kafka Connect connector configurations in a Kafka topic.

According the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-userguide-dist-worker-config):

> The replication factor of this topic should **always** be at least 3 for a production system, but cannot be larger than the number of Kafka brokers in the cluster.

I'm not sure, but this scenario might cause your issue: a broker with a single replica of config data becomes unavailable for some reason (like K8S behaviour), so Kafka Connect cannot get the current config state.

Please try to increase replication factor of `config.storage.topic` (from 1 to 3). Also check repliction factors of other config topics (`offset.storage.replication.factor`, `status.storage.replication.factor`).

Comment: are you sure I can do that when the cluster is online? From what I recall I tried that in past and it causes Kafka Connect unable to start. But I'll try that on test env.